# why does is_infinite() returns TRUE for the string '592e5399'?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$number1 = 1;
$number2 = 0;

$number3 = $number1/$number2 ;
```

$number3 will return float(INF) which is OK.

```
var_dump($number3 );
```

in order to identify INF, I can use is_infinite like below.

```
$check_Is_INF = is_infinite($number3);
```

$check_Is_INF above will return true - which is OK.

```
var_dump($check_Is_INF );
```

But why does this **always return TRUE** if I check this string: **592e5399**, like below

```
$number3 = '592e5399';
$check_Is_INF = is_infinite($number3);
var_dump($check_Is_INF );
```

Comment: Because of the `e` in the middle.

Comment: `592e5399` is `529 * (10 ^ 5399)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in the documentation for [is_infinite](https://php.net/is_infinite):

> Returns TRUE if val is infinite (positive or negative), like the
>   result of log(0) **or any value too big to fit into a float** on this
>   platform.

The number `592e5399` is in notation expression (because of the `e` that it contains), so it's a very huge number exceeding the float limit. Because of that it will be considered an *infinite* number.

Precisely, the `e` means `^` so the number will be `592 ^ 5399`.

---

A note about the type of the variable `$number3`:

you set it as String but thanks to the [PHP's Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), every value you use in an expression, will assume the type accordingly to the context when is it. In this case, the String is converted in number because the function `is_infinite` expects a number.

Comment: This is the correct answer. On a 64bit platform `PHP_FLOAT_MAX` is `1.7976931348623E+308`, where as OPs number is a lot bigger than that. The important part here is the `e` mathematical constant which is `2.71828`. Read more about `e` [here](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/Math/Math-e.htm). For example: `592e53`(notice I left out the other 2 ints from OPs number) is `59,100,000,000,000,000,000,576,016,664,592,256,840,144,512,808,336,808,352`. So you can imagine how big op's number is.

Comment: @user2342558 - OK. assuming one of my database record has this value. I want to check that value is INF (infinite). what is your recommendations to do this?

Comment: @Raa You may check if the database column contains the `e` char, where you instead expects only numbers.

Comment: @user2342558 - your answer help me a lot, thanks. I've accomplished this by checking the variable is NOT a string as well. 
if (is_infinite($number3) && !is_string($number3)) {

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is casting the string into a `float`

Function description from https://www.php.net/is_infinite

```
is_infinite ( float $val ) : bool
```

It doesn't matter if you call

- `is_infinite('592e5399')`
- `is_infinite(592e5399)`

Both will be cast to `float`, and you'll get the same response: `true`.

Comment: Its got little to do with the type in this case, as mentioned in the previous answer, its because of the size of the value - which is extremely big here. `592e5399` is a really, really big number - but it is finite, the computer just can't handle that big numbers.

Comment: Ah, right. It makes total sense. Thanks for the note :)